# Sqlite3 user defined datatype

Tags: sqlite

I can create table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable
(
name text,
surname varchar
)
```

I can also create table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable2
(
name BLABLA,
surname mygrandpaType
)
```

I know there is no diff between text and varchar in SQLite. But even in second table I can insert and select querys from it and works fine..
It does not make sense what is it use for datataype approach in SQLite ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any column with the exception of `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` can hold values of any type. The specified datatype is just a hint and it is called type affinity.

Determining type affinity:

> - If the declared type contains the string "INT" then it is assigned INTEGER affinity.
> - If the declared type of the column contains any of the strings "CHAR", "CLOB", or "TEXT" then that column has TEXT affinity. Notice that the type VARCHAR contains the string "CHAR" and is thus assigned TEXT affinity.
> - If the declared type for a column contains the string "BLOB" or if no type is specified then the column has affinity NONE.
> - If the declared type for a column contains any of the strings "REAL", "FLOA", or "DOUB" then the column has REAL affinity.
> - Otherwise, the affinity is NUMERIC.

Therefore your `BLABLA` column gets the `NUMERIC` affinity.

Further reading: https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html

Comment: it makes sense now :) but what if I want to keep files in db ? which type I should specify for that column ?

Comment: `BLOB`, but also consider not storing blobs in your database but rather store in filesystem and only the path in db.